# Each vs smart selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is better to use, the each function it self or using some smart selectors to do the same thing.

Example:

**EACH FUNCTION**

```
$('nav#mainNav > ul > li > ul').each(function(){
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('hasSub'); 
});
```

**SELECTOR**

```
var addClass = $('nav#mainNav > ul > li > ul').closest('li').addClass('hasSub');
```

Both of these do the same thing, however is there any point to doing one over the other?

Comment: And after that, they're functionally identical annd the second is just a tad shorter through syntactic sugar.

Comment: Whoops, that was an accident on my part, edited

Comment: In each you can probably replace closest('li') with parent()

Comment: the parent may not always be the li though, I could use `parent('li')`. But really, they're very similar

Comment: It will always be the parent with the selector `li > ul`

Comment: `parent('li')` is probably not what you think it is. That would select the parent _only if_ it's a `li`. It will work in this case tho. I think you're overspecifying anyway...

Comment: true, but that selector may change, regardless, nothing to do with my question.

Comment: You might also consider using `has()` for stuff like this - `$('nav#mainNav > ul > li').has('ul').addClass('hasSub');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly iteration (`.each`) should be used when applying logic that varies between elements. Otherwise, *implicit iteration* will do just fine.

Your code sample is almost exactly the same as the [`.each` API](http://api.jquery.com/each/) page:

> Note: most jQuery methods that return a jQuery object also loop
>   through the set of elements in the jQuery collection — a process known
>   as *implicit iteration*. When this occurs, it is often unnecessary to
>   explicitly iterate with the `.each()` method.

---

For example, instead of using a selector to select `ul`s nested inside `li`s and traverse a level up, you can also use `.each` applying a logic test for `li`s that contain `ul`s:

```
$('#mainNav > ul > li').each(function() {
   if ($(this).children('ul').length) {
       $(this).addClass('hasSub'); 
   }
});
```

Though this is more verbose, it does essentially the same thing.

---

For code-golf purposes, as mentioned in the comments and Bergi's answer, `li:has(ul)` would be the shortest way of achieving this without requiring a `.closest()` call. Though `:has` is not essentially the same as the children selector - `:has` looks for descendants (various levels deep) while `>` looks for direct children (1 level deep) - I believe it should work as well for this specific use case.

Comment: While others may have given me my answer, yours is the most direct and  straight from the docs. Thankyou!

Comment: No problem, I've added an example with `.each` logic test now. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

> Both of these do the same thing, however is there any point to doing one over the other?

Yes. The second one is shorter and more performant (since `.each` is called anyway internally from those methods). There is absolutely no reason to incorporate an `each` here - it's just as pointless as using `.each(function(){ $(this).addClass(…); })`.

Btw, maybe you're looking for the [`:has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), which would shorten your expression even more:

```
$('#mainNav > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass('hasSub');
```

If you want to be sure that the `ul` is a direct child of the list item, you still may want to use the suggestion from the comments (the `closest(li)` is always the direct parent of the ul):

```
$('nav#mainNav > ul > li > ul').parent().addClass('hasSub');
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is all I wanted and I got hailed by other comments on the code. :) Thanks mate.

Comment: Note that (though I believe this wouldn't matter in this specific use case) `:has(ul)` is not semantically equivalent to the children selector `> ul`, as `:has` looks for descendants recursively instead of just one level deep I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method instead which reads a lot better:

```
var addClass = $('nav#mainNav > ul > li').has('ul').addClass('hasSub');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most jQuery methods will operate on a collection of elements, and automatically iterate as if you'd used `.each()`. So one does not normally use `.each()` in simple cases like that.

However, if you need to perform multiple operations based on each element, it may be necessary to use `.each()`. E.g.

```
$('nav#mainNav > ul > li > ul').each(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('hasSub');
    $(this).closest('.otherClass').removeClass('.otherClass');
});
```

You *could* write this without `.each()` by using `.end()`:

```
$('nav#mainNav > ul > li > ul')
    .closest('li').addClass('hasSub').end()
    .closest('.otherClass').removeClass('.otherClass');
```

but I believe `.each()` makes the intent clearer (although indentation, like this, does a pretty good job as well).